# fetch weatherapi.com with async await react hooks

Tags: react-hooks, weather, weather-api

Can anyone help me why my code doesn't work to fetch API?
I have to build a weather app from several components, must build it structured.
My plan is to have one service component that I have API service in there. then I have to make 3 more components, search component to handle the city search, weatherToday component to show today weather, and weatherForecast component to show five days forecast.

And I have to fetch the API with async an await. Here is the code that I tried(just now I have the code in my App.js just to try if my fetch work)

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  const fetchData = async () => {
    await fetch(
      `http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=1d172d3904e246849d3183628230802&q=Stockholm&days=6&aqi=no&alerts=no`
    )
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h3>{data.location.name}</h3>
      <p>{data.current.temp_c}</p>
      <p>{data.location.localtime}</p>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Open your browser's developer tools. Look at the console. **Read the error messages!**

Comment: put a .catch() then console.log the error and post it here for us to help you

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to React and StackOverflow!

There's a few issues here:

The main issue is `CORS`. You can't call this API from your browser - it's meant to be called from a server (backend). I highly recommend using `Next.js` since you like `React`, it uses that as it's framework - but it allows you to have `Server Components`, essentially an `Express` backend, so that you can perform this API call - then retrieve that data using this client component just to display the data (not to fetch it).

Another issue (but not the problem here) is reusing the `data` variable in the local scope of `then((data) =>` is not good when you have `data` defined higher up in the component scope for your state. Use `then((d) =>` instead.

I created a Next.js 13 sandbox for you with this working API call to get you started:

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/broken-field-4nsp1p

In Next.js 13, you can use the `app` folder, where every component is a `Server Component` by default. Then you can create `Client Component`, like the one you have above - you simply have to add `use client` to the very top of the file, that's it.

Since Next.js 13 is very new (the `app` folder and concept of `Server Components` very new and bound to change), you would want to potentially just stick with the `pages` folder.

In there, you'll see the client component which calls the `api` folder's `getWeather` API call.

Finally, you shared your private key with the public. You need to destroy and regenerate that key now:

*From the WeatherAPI.com Docs:*

**Authentication**

> API access to the data is protected by an API key. If at anytime, you
> find the API key has become vulnerable, please regenerate the key
> using Regenerate button next to the API key.

https://www.weatherapi.com/docs/

If don't want to use Next.js - then you'll need to use some sort of backend, like `Firebase Functions` or `Google Cloud Functions`, etc. Next.js is probably the easiest thing to adapt if you like React though!

Learn about Next.js 13 & `/app` folder:

https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/getting-started

Learn about Next.js 12 & `/pages` folder:

https://nextjs.org/docs

**Implementing Fetch via Next.js 13**

**app/head.tsx**

```js
export default function Head() {
  return (
    <>
      <title>Weather App</title>
      <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
    </>
  );
}
```

**app.layout.tsx**

```js
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      {/*
        <head /> will contain the components returned by the nearest parent
        head.tsx. Find out more at https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/head
      */}
      <head />
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

**app/page.tsx**

```js
const App = async () => {
  console.log("App.js");

  const results = await fetch(
    `http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=1d172d3904e246849d3183628230802&q=Stockholm&days=6&aqi=no&alerts=no`
  );

  const json = await results.json();
  console.log("json", json);

  return (
    <>
      <h3>{json.location.name}</h3>
      <p>{json.location.temp_c}</p>
      <p>{json.location.localtime}</p>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

When visiting either `/` or `/weather`, you will see the same results, since the example is implemented in both v12 and v13:

[image]

**--- OR --- Implementing Fetch via Next.js 12**

**pages/weather.tsx**

```js
async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch("/api/getWeather");
  console.log("res", res);
  // The return value is *not* serialized
  // You can return Date, Map, Set, etc.

  // Recommendation: handle errors
  if (!res.ok) {
    // This will activate the closest `error.js` Error Boundary
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
  }

  const json = await res.json();

  console.log({ json });

  return json;
}

export default async function Page() {
  const data = await getData();
  console.log("data", data);
  return (
    <main>
      <h3>{data.location.name}</h3>
      <p>{data.current.temp_c}</p>
      <p>{data.location.localtime}</p>
    </main>
  );
}
```

**pages/api/getWeather.ts**

```js
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  const results = await fetch(
    `http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=1d172d3904e246849d3183628230802&q=Stockholm&days=6&aqi=no&alerts=no`
  );
  const json = await results.json();
  console.log("json", json);
  res.status(200).send(json);
}
```

Remember to revoke your exposed secret API key.

I hope this helps you start building your app. Good luck!